# Comparação de dois números em JS. Onde está o erro?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, comparação, módulo-ecmascript

Preciso de uma coisa simples, mas não sei o que está dando errado ou rodar. Além de comparar se os números são maiores, menores ou iguais, preciso também adicionar uma condição em que se um numero foi maior que o outro E o módulo não for zero, ele resulta em uma resposta. Além saberia onde estou errando? Muito obrigada.

```
function modulo(randomNumberA, randomNumberB) {
    if (randomNumberA > randomNumberB) {
      console.log(`The number ${randomNumberA} is bigger than ${randomNumberB}`)
    } else if (randomNumberA === randomNumberB) {
      console.log(`The number ${randomNumberA} is equal to ${randomNumberB}`)
    } else if (randomNumberA < randomNumberB) {
      console.log(`The number ${randomNumberA} is less than ${randomNumberB}`)
    } else if (randomNumberA > randomNumberB && randomNumberA % randomNumberB !== 0) {
      console.log('The modulo of ' + randomNumberA + ' % ' + randomNumberB + ' is ' + randomNumberA % randomNumberB)
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: Um número sempre vai ser maior, menor ou igual à outro (3 condições). Como você utilizou uma estrutura de if's encadeados, que diz tente a primeira condição, caso não consiga tente a segunda, caso não consiga tente a terceira e caso não consiga tente a quarta, só que a quarta nunca vai ser tentada, pois uma das 3 anteriores já terá sido selecionada. Você pode resolver colocando o if do módulo dentro do primeiro ou colocando o quarto if como o primeiro.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer isso, mas ainda sim não funcionou. Funciona claro, mas não passa no meu teste, porque dá duas respostas ao invés de uma só.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi do problema você quer informar qual número é maior entre os dois e se o módulo entre ambos é 0. Usando as funções Math.max e Math.min para encontrar o maior e o menor valor entre os fornecidos você consegue evitar encher o código de if's e else's. Então uma solução para seu problema poderia ser:

```
function modulo(randomNumberA, randomNumberB) {

    // Função Math.max retorna o MAIOR valor entre os fornecidos
    console.log('O maior valor é: ', Math.max(randomNumberA, randomNumberB))

    // Função Math.min retorna o MENOR valor entre os fornecidos
    console.log('O menor valor é: ', Math.min(randomNumberA, randomNumberB))

    // Printa qual número é maior e qual é o menor
    console.log(`The number ${Math.max(randomNumberA, randomNumberB)} is bigger than ${Math.min(randomNumberA,randomNumberB)}`)
      
      // Módulo do maior valor entre as duas entradas e o menor valor entre as duas entradas
      if(Math.max(randomNumberA, randomNumberB) % Math.min(randomNumberA, randomNumberB) === 0) {
          console.log('The modulo of ' + Math.max(randomNumberA, randomNumberB) + ' % ' + Math.min(randomNumberA, randomNumberB) + ' is ' + Math.max(randomNumberA, randomNumberB) % Math.min(randomNumberA, randomNumberB))
      }
}
```

---

O código da pergunta não está funcionando como o esperado pois o IF... ELSE IF... ELSE... é um único bloco de execução, e é finalizado assim que uma das condições é verdadeira (ou nenhuma, entrando no ELSE...).

Quando o primeiro IF é verdadeiro, o bloco é encerrado, e as demais condições não são verificadas. Para fazer um teste pode-se utilizar IFs ao invés de ELSE IFs.

```
function modulo(randomNumberA, randomNumberB) {
    if (randomNumberA > randomNumberB) {
      console.log(`The number ${randomNumberA} is bigger than ${randomNumberB}`)
    } 
    if (randomNumberA === randomNumberB) {
      console.log(`The number ${randomNumberA} is equal to ${randomNumberB}`)
    } 
    if (randomNumberA < randomNumberB) {
      console.log(`The number ${randomNumberA} is less than ${randomNumberB}`)
    } 
    if (randomNumberA > randomNumberB && randomNumberA % randomNumberB !== 0) {
      console.log('The modulo of ' + randomNumberA + ' % ' + randomNumberB + ' is ' + randomNumberA % randomNumberB)
    }
  }
```

Dessa forma, cada IF é um bloco de execução independente, e então todas as condições serão validadas.

Comment: Sim isso seria ótimo para o código ficar mais objetivo, mas ainda não resolve meu problema :( Daquela forma que está dado, com todos os if/else ainda não roda cada um independentemente. O bigger (maior que) e o caso do módulo entram em colisão, um em cima do outro.

Comment: Editei a resposta explicando o porquê do seu código não funcionar como esperado e dando uma solução para o mesmo

Comment: SIMMM! Entendi o que você falou fez super sentido, por isso funcionava ou só o maior que ou o maior com o módulo... Super obrigada Victor! Agora finalmente rodou certinho e eu entendi :)